# How does one deploy through Intune the Microsoft.Office.Desktop Appx Package?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-10, microsoft-intune

Knowing that there is the Office 365 ProPlus Click-to-run installer template within Intune, I wonder if there may be a way to deploy Office through the Store for Business.

We are finding Office to be pre-installed on some new Windows 10 devices. These have not been installed using the MSI or Click-to-run installer, but as an AppX (MSIX?) package. Get-AppxProvisionedPackage shows the display name to be "Microsoft.Office.Desktop" and the Store app shows that it has Add-ons for each installed component of the Office suite.

For our devices which do not already have Office installed, how would one deploy through Intune the Microsoft.Office.Desktop Appx Package?

Maybe, I am getting ahead of Microsoft on this and it will eventually show up as an option in the Store for Business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft.Office.Desktop app comes from the Office Single Image OPK. See the section "**Add Office apps to your image**" in the document "[System builder deployment of Windows 10 for desktop editions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/system-builder-deployment-of-windows-10-for-desktop-editions#update-images-manually-by-using-audit-mode-online-servicing)".

Thank you to Daniel for sharing this insight and for the excellent blog post "[Provisioned App Packages in Windows 10 Enterprise / Windows 10 Pro](https://blog.danic.net/provisioned-app-packages-in-windows-10-enterprise-windows-10-pro/)"!

We now [uninstall this and the other Office provisioned apps](https://serverfault.com/a/938996/6079) that block the installation of the Office 365 installation package provided by Intune.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to install the msi version of office or the Windows store app? If you are trying to install the msi version try this resource to deploy an msi package with intune:
https://osddeployment.dk/2017/04/29/how-to-windows-installer-through-mdm-msi-to-windows-10-with-intune-in-azure/

For the windows store version of Office in our intune setup Microsoft office just shows up as an option on the mobile app list and we can deploy it from there which is the way I would recommend to go. I do not recall having to purchase it from the Windows store for business portal.

Comment: Not trying to install the classic MSI version of Office, nor the limited mobile versions. We have seen full versions of Office 365 ProPlus pre-installed as an App on consumer laptops and, believing this is the future, would like to replicate this in our enterprise.

Comment: The Microsoft Office under mobile apps is the Office 365 ProPlus Suite. It is the full version of Office ProPlus. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iasf0.png

Comment: You could also use the Office 16.5 OPK to preinstall Office in your wim before you load windows. Scroll down about half way on this page and there is a section on preloading office. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oem-deployment-of-windows-10-for-desktop-editions

Comment: We are not installing Windows. We are using AutoPilot. The machines start with a clean copy of Windows 10 and Intune is supposed to take it from there. Unfortunately, some of them have been coming with the "Microsoft.Office.Desktop" AppX package pre-installed. Installing Office 365 ProPlus with the current Intune solution causes duplication, with Office being installed in two different ways (MSI and AppX).